# GhostScript PDF 1.5 (from tiff to PDF with ImageMagick) convert to PDF/A

Tags: pdf, ghostscript, acrobat, verify, pdfa

I need to create a PDF/A from a Folder of Tiff Files.
Creating a PDF (1.5) is working with ImageMagick.
But Converting this PDF to a PDF/A using Ghostscript is a problem.

My GhostScript cmd:

```
-dPDFA=2 -dNOOUTERSAVE -sProcessColorModel=DeviceRGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -o "C:\Temp\TestData\TIFF to PDF Imagemagick\pdfa.pdf" "C:\Temp\TestData\TIFF to PDF Imagemagick\PDFA_def.ps" -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 "C:\Temp\TestData\TIFF to PDF Imagemagick\test.pdf"
```

Also tryed:

```
-dPDFA=2 -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -sOutputFile="C:\Temp\TestData\TIFF to PDF Imagemagick\pdfa.pdf" "C:\Temp\TestData\TIFF to PDF Imagemagick\PDFA_def.ps" "C:\Temp\TestData\TIFF to PDF Imagemagick\test.pdf"
```

my PDFA_def.ps is the GS standard with:

```
/ICCProfile (AdobeRGB1998.icc) % Customise
```

The created PDF/? is not passing the "Verify compliance with PDF/A-2b" preflight in Adobe Acrobat:

```
Error
Metadata missing (XMP)
PDF/A entry missing
Syntax problem: Indirect object “endobj” keyword not preceded by an EOL marker
Syntax problem: Stream dictionary improperly formatted
```

Also not the https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx validator:

```
File    pdfa.pdf
Compliance  pdf1.5
Result  Document does not conform to PDF/A.
Details 
Validating file "pdfa.pdf" for conformance level pdf1.5
XML line 10:212: xmlParseCharRef: invalid xmlChar value 0.
The document does not conform to the requested standard.
The document's meta data is either missing or inconsistent or corrupt.
The document does not conform to the PDF 1.5 standard.
Done.
```

Also tryed VeraPDF ....

What kind of settings have I forgotten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With this command its now running:

```
-dPDFA=2 -sColorConversionStrategy=RGB -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -dPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1 -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -o "C:\Temp\TestData\tiff2pdfa\pdfatest.pdf" "C:\Temp\TestData\tiff2pdfa\PDFA\PDFA_def.ps" "C:\Temp\TestData\tiff2pdfa\test.pdf"
```

Thanks to:
[Batch Convert PDF to PDF/A - MARK BERRY](https://www.mcbsys.com/blog/2018/10/batch-convert-pdf-to-pdf-a-2018-edition/)

But i have still some Error:

```
GPL Ghostscript 9.25: UTF16BE text string detected in DOCINFO cannot be represented 
in XMP for PDF/A 1, discarding DOCINFO
Processing pages 1 through 56.
Page 1
GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Setting Overprint Mode to 1
 not permitted in PDF/A-2, overprint mode not set
```

Should I be thinking about this "Overpirnt Mode"?

Comment: Well obviously that's entirely up to you. PDF/A doesn't permit overprint mode to be 1, your original document obviously has an overprint mode of 1. Removing it has implications for rendering the file, but you can't keep it and create a PDF/A file. I can't think of any good reason why a PDF file created from an image would set OPM anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Well there's quite a few problems here.

You haven't said what version of Ghostscript you are using, nor have you supplied an example file to experiment with. You also haven't given the back channel output which might contain additional information.

You can't use the supplied model PFA_def.ps without modification, at the very least you need to modify the /ICCProfile entry to point to a real valid ICC profile. I suspect this has caused pdfwrite to abort PDF/A-2 production, which would normally be mentioned in the back channel output.

You haven't set -dColorConversionStrategy, just setting the ProcessColorModel is not sufficient, pdfwrite will mostly ignore that. If you don't tell pdfwrite that you want colours converted to a different space, it will preserve them unchanged, regardless of the Process color model.

Comment: Im using version 9.22. In the third codeline you can see that im using AdobeRGB1998.icc. In the second codeline i tryed the RGB ColorConversionStrategy.

Comment: Your "third codeline" says "(AdobeRGB1998.icc)", there's no path specified at all. Unless you have an ICC profile with that filename in the current working directory, it won't be found. I can't immediately see any difference between your 'second codeline' and the answer you posted as 'working'

Comment: I used the "PDFA_def.ps" file from the posted link. Thx

Comment: The link includes instructions for placing theAdobeRGB1998.icc profile in a specific location, and has a customised PDFA_def.ps which points to that location for the ICC profile. In short, exactly what I told you in my answer.